# I'm using reactive_sliding_segmented package. How can I go to next segment on clicking a button on Parent Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the value of segment control when button is clicked in parent widget.
If button and segment control are in same widget I can easily change the value of segment control but if they are in different widgets how can I change?

This is my main.dart

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                const TabView(),
                ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {//go to next segment on click}, 
                 child: const Text('Next'))
              ],
            )),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

This is my tab_view.dart

```
class TabView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabView> createState() => _TabViewState();
}

class _TabViewState extends State<TabView> {
  FormGroup formGroup = FormGroup({
    'name': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'note': FormControl<String>()
  });

  final FormControl<String> segmentControl =
      FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReactiveForm(
      formGroup: formGroup,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ReactiveSlidingSegmentedControl<String, String>(
            formControl: segmentControl,
            children: const {
              'name': Text('Name'),
              'note': Text('Note'),
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            return ReactiveValueListenableBuilder(
                formControl: segmentControl,
                builder: (context, field, child) {
                  return _buildView(field as FormControl<String>, formGroup);
                });
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildView(FormControl<String> control, FormGroup formGroup) {
    if ((control.value != 'name') && formGroup.control('name').invalid) {
      formGroup.control('name').markAsTouched();
      control.value = 'name';
    }
    switch (control.value) {
      case 'name':
        return ReactiveTextField(
          formControlName: 'name',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
        );
      case 'note':
        return ReactiveTextField(
          formControlName: 'note',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Note'),
        );
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any method so that the child Widget knows button has been clicked in Parent widget and change the value of segment control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two final variables `next` and `prev`, and ask inside the constructor,  set to `false` initially in `TabView`. Override `didUpdateWidget` and put the logic of changing the `segmentControl` to reflect `next`/`prev` value by finding the current value and next value from map given inside the `children` param.

Make MyApp Stateful widget declare two state variables `_next` and `_prev` alter their value on prev/next button pass these value as param to `TabView(prev:_prev,next:_next)` and you are good to go.

A detailed example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ///HERE
  bool _next = false;
  bool _prev = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            TabView(
              ///HERE
              next: _next,
              prev: _prev,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ///HERE
                    setState(() {
                      _next = false;
                      _prev = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Prev')),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ///HERE
                    setState(() {
                      _next = true;
                      _prev = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Next'))
            ])
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TabView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabView({Key? key, this.prev = false, this.next = false})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool prev;
  final bool next;

  @override
  State<TabView> createState() => _TabViewState();
}

class _TabViewState extends State<TabView> {
  FormGroup formGroup = FormGroup({
    'name': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'note': FormControl<String>()
  });
  final List<Widget> control = [const Text('Name'), const Text('Note')];

  final FormControl<int> segmentControl = FormControl<int>(value: 0);

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(TabView oldWidget) {
    if (widget.next) {
      final nextIndex =
          min((segmentControl.value ?? -1) + 1, control.length - 1);

      segmentControl.value = nextIndex;
    }
    if (widget.prev) {
      final prevIndex = max((segmentControl.value ?? -1) - 1, 0);

      segmentControl.value = prevIndex;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReactiveForm(
      formGroup: formGroup,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ReactiveSlidingSegmentedControl<int, int>(
            formControl: segmentControl,
            children: control.asMap(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          ReactiveValueListenableBuilder(
              formControl: segmentControl,
              builder: (context, control, child) {
                return _buildView(segmentControl.value!, formGroup);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildView(int index, FormGroup formGroup) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return ReactiveTextField(
          formControlName: 'name',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
        );
      case 1:
        return ReactiveTextField(
            formControlName: 'note',
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Note'));
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

A more flexible approach would be to add callback function `onTraversalFallback` instead of hardcoding.
One usecase may be: in stepper form you want next to trigger tabview next tab until last tab is reached. if the `last tab` is reached move to `stepCount+1`.

For that a little tweak is needed. Hope one finds useful

```
class TabView extends StatefulWidget {
/*...*/
final VoidCallback? onTraversalFallback;
/*...*/
}
```

```
class _TabViewState extends State<TabView> {
/*...*/
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(SaveElearningCourseDetailsForm oldWidget) {
    if (widget.next) {
      final nextIndex =
          min((segmentControl.value ?? -1) + 1, control.length - 1);
      if (nextIndex == segmentControl.value) {
        widget.onTraversalFallback?.call();
      } else {
        segmentControl.value = nextIndex;
      }
    }
    if (widget.prev) {
      final prevIndex = max((segmentControl.value ?? -1) - 1, 0);
      if (prevIndex == segmentControl.value) {
        widget.onTraversalFallback?.call();
      } else {
        segmentControl.value = prevIndex;
      }
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
/*...*/
}
```

on caller side you can do something like:

```
TabView(
              ///HERE
              next: _next,
              prev: _prev,
              onTraversalFallback: () {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_prev) {
                      _currentStep -= 1;
                      _prev = false;
                    }
                    if (_next) {
                      _currentStep + 1;
                      _next = false;
                    }
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
```

Comment: you may also add provide callback function say ```onTraversalFallback``` instead of hardcoding nextIndex to control value or value+/-1 which gives flexibility to run certain logic in parent widget.

one usecase may be: in stepper form you want next to trigger tabview next tab until last tab is reached . if last tab is reached move to stepCount+1